# Django Interchanging the urls by overiding regex part

Tags: python, django

When requesting[GET]  127.0.0.1:8000/restaurant/1 i get a clean json and 200 status code

```
urlpatterns = [

url(r'^restaurant',views.Restaurant_List_Create.as_view(), name='all_restaurants'),
url(r'^restaurant/(?P<pk>\d+)',views.Restaurant_Retrive.as_view(), name='specified_restaurant'),

]
```

but when i interchange the url codes it runs the views.Restaurant_List_Create.as_view() (overrides the regex url)

```
urlpatterns = [

url(r'^restaurant/(?P<pk>\d+)',views.Restaurant_Retrive.as_view(), name='specified_restaurant'),    
url(r'^restaurant',views.Restaurant_List_Create.as_view(), name='all_restaurants'),


]
```

Comment: try changing the url to `r'^restaurant/(?P<pk>\d+)/$'`

Answer (score 2):

You url matches both because you don't have included $ sign at the end of your urls.

You can change them as follow :

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^restaurant/(?P<pk>\d+)$',views.Restaurant_Retrive.as_view(), name='specified_restaurant'),    
  url(r'^restaurant$',views.Restaurant_List_Create.as_view(), name='all_restaurants'),
]
```